# history.push doesn't redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Using react-router v4 and `BrowserRouter` I'm calling history.push to navigate to a different path. Unfortunately the url change in the browser but there is no navigation. I'm not sure if composing route is the right way to go or am I missing something?

```
<Route render={({history}) =>
    <div className="nav" onClick={() => {history.push('/new-route');}}><i 
    className="fa fa-user"/></div>}
/>
```

Comment: Update: I tried `props.history.push("/new-route");` but no joy

Comment: Did you try `withRouter`?

Comment: Yes, I did (I don't know of any other way to generate `props.history`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the context api

```js
const Button = (props, context) => (
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => {
      // context.history.push === history.push
      context.history.push('/new-location')
    }}
  >
    Click Me!
  </button>
)

// you need to specify the context type so that it
// is available within the component
Button.contextTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.shape({
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! unfortunately, the result is the same. The browser url is changed but to get the redirect to work I need to add `location.reload()`